# Meaning of this Scheme interpreter output?

Tags: scheme

I'm working through Simply Scheme. I'm using DrRacket with this as my definitions file

https://gist.github.com/alexgian/5b351f367169b40a4ad809f0bb718e1f

I'm on exercise 17.3, which says

[https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch17/lists.html](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ebh/ssch17/lists.html)

> Describe the value returned by this invocation of map
>
> `> (map (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (+ x y))) '(1 2 3 4))`

In DrRacket, I get the following output for that invocation of map:

`(#<procedure> #<procedure> #<procedure> #<procedure>)`

I know that lambda lets you return procedures. I'm having a hard time figuring out what procedure is being returned for some reason though, what exactly is happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply substitute in turn every value of the list to the variable x in the inner function. In other words, the result is equal to:

```
(list (lambda (y) (+ 1 y))
      (lambda (y) (+ 2 y))
      (lambda (y) (+ 3 y))
      (lambda (y) (+ 4 y)))
```

a list of four functions, each of them increasing its parameter by a different value.